# Python : Iterate a list which is shared by several method in a class

Tags: python, class

I'm using `tornado.websocket`, where class-methods are overrides of the `WebSocketHandler` methods. Anyway, my code look like that:

```
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    current_ninja_pool = enumerate(return_dependency_lvl_0())
    current_ninja = next(current_ninja_pool)
    file_to_upload = []

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        logging.info("A client connected.")
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        if condition:
            do_this()
    else:
        do_that()
        self.current_ninja = next(self.current_ninja_pool)
        self.run()

def on_message(self, message):
    do_a_lot_of_stuff()
    if message == 'next one':
        self.current_ninja = next(self.current_ninja_pool)

def on_close(self):
    logging.info("A client disconnected")
```

So, what I want is to be able to iterate my `enumerate`, so that every element can be processed in the methods `run` or `on_message` depending on how my client-websocket will answer. The problem is that I want to iterate under particular conditions, and I don't have a clue on how to do this. Since I'm not very familiar with the way you manipulate class- and instance-variables, I'm probably missing a point here.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need an iterator. Luckily, `enumerate` already returns an iterator; you just need to access that, rather than storing the current item.

I also suspect that `current_ninja_pool` should be an instance variable, not a class one (which would be shared across *all* instances of the class).

```
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.current_ninja_pool = enumerate(return_dependency_lvl_0())
        file_to_upload = []

        def run(self):
            item = next(self.current_ninja_pool)
            do_something_with(item)
```

Comment: Since I need to iterate when i'm calling a specific function, do you think it would be a good approach to use a generator instead of enumerate ?